# getting all last id when I use union all and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

How to change the following code to get the max id of all sets of triples (nr1, n2, n3)?
Each set of triples occurs several times (several id). I want to get the max id of each triple. for example:

```
id    Number1   Number2   Number3   Number4   Number5                                                                       
66       2         3         4         7         9
74       2         3         5         6         8                        
102      3         7         8         9        10
123      3         6         7         9        10
157      1         2         3         4         5   
188      1         2         3         5         7
```

answer(two first rows (order by count)):

```
nr1   nr2   nr3   count   max_id                                            
 2     3     5      3       188
 3     7     9      3       123
```

I tried to add id in select and having but got incomplete results. Please help.

```
select nr1,nr2,nr3, count(*)
from         (select Number1 as nr1, Number2 as nr2, Number3 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number1 as nr1, Number2 as nr2, Number4 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number1 as nr1, Number2 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number1 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number4 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number1 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number1 as nr1, Number4 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number2 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number4 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number2 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number2 as nr1, Number4 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from tab
              union all
              select Number3 as nr1, Number4 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from tab) g
group by nr1, nr2, nr3
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, nr1, nr2, nr3
```

Comment: table is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

the last in DESC order is the first in ASC so  you could use limit 1  for ASC

```
    select nr1,nr2,nr3, count(*)
    from         (select Number1 as nr1, Number2 as nr2, Number3 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number1 as nr1, Number2 as nr2, Number4 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number1 as nr1, Number2 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number1 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number4 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number1 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number1 as nr1, Number4 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number2 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number4 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number2 as nr1, Number3 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number2 as nr1, Number4 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from table
                  union all
                  select Number3 as nr1, Number4 as nr2, Number5 as nr3 from table) g
    group by nr1, nr2, nr3
    ORDER BY count(*) ASC, nr1, nr2, nr3
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Perhaps I have expressed myself badly. Each set of triples occurs several times (several id). I want to get the max id of each triple. for example: the first set: (2,3,5) - id (74,157,188); the second set (3,7,9) - id (66,102,123). In addition to what I get now in response from the database I want to get the max id for each set: (188,123)

Comment: for avoid " badly expression" you should updated  your question add  a proper data sample   (as  tabular text) and the expected  result . Read  a sample in a comment is impossible  ..

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data structure.  It would be better to have one row per id and per number.

This is going to look complicated.  In what is unusual, I will start with a view (MySQL does not support CTEs):

```
create view better_data as
    select id, number1 as num, 1 as which from tab union all
    select id, number2 as num, 2 as which from tab union all
    select id, number3 as num, 3 as which from tab union all
    select id, number4 as num, 4 as which from tab union all
    select id, number5 as num, 5 as which from tab;
```

Then, you can generate all triples using:

```
select distinct bd1.num, bd2.num, bd3.num
from better_data bd1 cross join
     better_data bd2 cross join
     better_data bd3
where bd1.num < bd2.num and bd2.num < bd3.num;
```

Now, you can count these with aggregation:

```
select triples.num1, triples.num2, triples.num3, count(*) as cnt
from (select distinct bd1.num as num1, bd2.num as num2, bd3.num as num3
      from better_data bd1 cross join
           better_data bd2 cross join
           better_data bd3
      where bd1.num < bd2.num and bd2.num < bd3.num
     ) triples left join
     t
     on triples.num1 in (tab.number1, tab.number2, tab.number3, tab.number4, tab.number5) and
        triples.num2 in (tab.number1, tab.number2, tab.number3, tab.number4, tab.number5) and
        triples.num3 in (tab.number1, tab.number2, tab.number3, tab.number4, tab.number5)
group by triples.num1, triples.num2, triples.num3
order by count(*) desc;
```